# Google Maps API, Directions From Marker To Marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so I have a map with lots of markers plotted. I want to be able to right click a marker and select "start point", then right click another marker and select "destination point".

I would then remove all markers and only show the two markers ive clicked with the directions drawn on the map.

I have no idea where to begin here, i am new to jquery. here is my code so far
I have stripped out non important code to make it as small as possible:

```
    window.onload = function () {

        var markerarray = new Array();

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };



        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),      mapOptions);
        var image = 'marker.png';

        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var isCheckedD4 = $('#<%= D4.ClientID %>').is(':checked');
            var icon = "";
            var fred;

            if (isCheckedcat == true) {
                switch (data.category) {
                    case 'A1':
                        if (isCheckedA1 == true) {
                            icon = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/A1/0066FF/FFFFFF/FF5050";
                            fred = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            icon = "";
                            fred = false;
                        }
                        break;                  
                          }
                         }


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title,

                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon),
                visible: fred,
                draggable: false,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            markerarray.push(marker);

            (function (marker, data) {
                var markernameprev;
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {

                    infoWindow.setContent(data.name);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

                    for (var i = 0; i < markerarray.length; i++) {
                        markerarray[i].setAnimation(null);
                    }

                    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

                });

            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need is [**directions api**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) and [**marker docs**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers). After you read these carefully, you can

1. add `clickListener` to your markers
2. using the two selected markers' `lat/lng` info to generate direction (there's everything you need to learn in the link given above).

Hope this gives you a starting point.